# Sqoop: Avro with Gzip Codec failing

Tags: gzip, sqoop, avro

When trying to import tables to HDFS using Sqoop with --as-avrodatafile and GzipCodec, it is failing with below exception, I'm running this CDH7 Cloudera quickstart docker image

Is there a reason we cannot use Gzip with Avro or is it some missing configuration that is causing this.

**Note**: Gzip works when writing without the --as-avrodatafile switch

```
Error: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Unrecognized codec: gzip
        at org.apache.avro.file.CodecFactory.fromString(CodecFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AvroOutputFormat.configureDataFileWriter(AvroOutputFormat.java:63)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AvroOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(AvroOutputFormat.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:647)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:767)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Avro [CodecFactory](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/file/CodecFactory.java)

```
  /** Maps a codec name into a CodecFactory.
   *
   * Currently there are five codecs registered by default:
   * <ul>
   *   <li>{@code null}</li>
   *   <li>{@code deflate}</li>
   *   <li>{@code snappy}</li>
   *   <li>{@code bzip2}</li>
   *   <li>{@code xz}</li>
   * </ul>
   */
```

So gzip is supported for other output formats in sqoop but not for avro.